# Facebook C# SDK and the dreaded "Object with ID 'XXXXX'' does not exist... " exception

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

First off thank you very much for all your hard work on the Facebook C# SDK. It has made my life much easier.

I'm attempting to use the Facebook C# SDK to perform /items_batch calls to the Commerce Manager API.

My code looks like this:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
dynamic facebookClientResult;
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.access_token = "XXXXXX|YYYYYYY"; 
parameters.item_type = "DESTINATION";
// Simple object that serializes to a requests object as per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch#supported-fields-destination
parameters.requests = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemsBatchPolicy.ItemsBatchModel);
facebookClientResult = facebookClient.Post($"/{itemsBatchPolicy.ApiVersion}/{itemsBatchPolicy.CatalogId}/items_batch", parameters);
```

No matter how I tweak my parameters the exception message coming back is always the same:

```
Facebook.FacebookApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=(GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported post request. 
  Object with ID 'XXXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. 
  Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
  Source=Facebook
  StackTrace:
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at [My code]...
```

Might anyone have some insight as to how to address this error?

Thank you very much,
vic

Comment: Well, have you confirmed the item exists, that your access token has the right permissions to access it, etc.?

Comment: Hello Ceejazoz;
Thank you for your response.
The catalog does exist, and the catalog and it's associated app are both in development mode.

To my understanding, that means no explicit permissions need be applied.

Comment: Explicit permissions are definitely required. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/setup/api-setup (See the screenshot below "Then switch to the Catalogs asset type, search for the catalog connected to your Commerce Account page and toggle the Manage Catalog permission under Admin Access.")

Comment: Hello Ceejayoz; Indeed, explicit permissions are required. We ended creating another user account, granting that account the required permissions, and then using that user account's access token to facilitate communication via the API. Thank you very much for your assistance!